# Open a file in Github.com from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I have a project cloned from github.com, now I have option to make changes commit changes and push changes in Visual Studio. When I am in Visual Studio I want to see a source file in github.com

Is there an option to open a source file in Github.com from Visual Studio (2017,2019 - windows) using keyboard shortcut or context menu?

I didn't find this option in team explorer and any of the context menu

Comment: clone source from github to local hard drive and open solution

Comment: @magicandre1981 I already have cloned project and I updated my question. Thanks!!

Comment: In Git when you clone a repo you download all the history too.

Comment: You're wanting to perform a diff between the original file and what you've changed it to? That's it?

Comment: sorry may be I didn't put the question correctly. All I need to do is access the file in github.com Example: I have this project (https://github.com/csharp-today/GitHubHelloWorld.git) cloned and I opened the project in Visual Studio and opened program.cs file. Now I want to view Program.cs in web browser, I can go to github.com -> go to project and navigate to the file I need. But is there a link in Visual studio which can take directly to the file (https://github.com/csharp-today/GitHubHelloWorld/blob/master/MyFirstGitHubApplication/MyFirstGitHubApplication/Program.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Found a visual studio extension "**Open on GitHub**"

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neuecc.OpenonGitHub

It is a open source project

https://github.com/neuecc/Open-on-GitHub